# SQL Server 2008 R2: Import table from text file when column names have a / in them

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sap-bw

How do you import a table into a database from a text file when that table has /'s in the column names?

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 table with columns that have /'s in their name.  (SAP Database)
For example:  `/BIC/FIC_SD001` has a column named `/BIC/O_CST_00`.

I have done an export (using the Import/Export Wizard) of this table to a text file and the slashes are there.

When I import the table into a different database (using the wizard) all the /'s from the column are removed and replaced with spaces.
The above column now looks like this:  `BIC 0_CST_00`

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the step of the wizard called **Select Source Tables and Views**, you have to click **Edit Mappings...** Over there you can manually change the Destination column names (setting back the missing slashes).

Comment: You are right that would work, but I have 20 tables with around 40 columns per table that are like this. I should have been more specific in the question, Do you know of a scripted/automatic way to do this?

Comment: No, I can't think of an automatic solution. Actually, this is clearly a bug and I think you should talk directly to Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BCP Utility to import or export data from sql server to text file or vice verse.

```
    BCP Database.TableName out "Location of the text file " -c -S ServerName -T
```

The above command will load the data from sql server table to the flat file

To load the data from flat file to SQL server the command is as follows :-

```
    BCP Database.TableName in "Location of the text file " -c -S ServerName -T
```

The above 2 commands will work for Windows Authentication

Comment: I have tried BCP bwq./BIC/FIC_SD001 out "c:\temp\sd001" -c -S <servername> -T and BCP bwq."/BIC/FIC_SD001" out "c:\temp\sd001" -c -S <servername> -T. Both are getting the error: An error occurred while processing the command line. P.S. I put the actual server name for <servername>

Comment: If you have a trusted connection with the server, you can remove the -S flag. Otherwise, try -S<servername> without any blank space. E.g: -Smyserver

Comment: An example of BCP out command for Adventure Work database having windows authentication  is as follows:  BCP AdventureWorksLT.SalesLT.Address out "C:\temp\sd001" -c -S CBR-DEL1156\SQL2005 -T       You will get that error if you don't write the database ,schema and the table name properly

Comment: Thanks for your help...I figured it out. I needed to add [] around db, schema and table.  From a command prompt on the server here is what I typed: **BCP [BWQ].[bwq].[/BIC/FIC_SD001] out "c:\temp\sd001.txt" -c -T**